# Typescript default function parameter based on generic's type

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to refactor the following to specify a default implementation for the `extractor` parameter of the `handleEvent` method when `TEvent` is of type `DefaultEvent`.

Instead of calling:

```js
handleEvent<DefaultEvent>({value: "test"}, (e) => e.value);
```

I would like the following to be equivalent if possible:

```js
handleEvent<DefaultEvent>({value: "test"});
```

```js
type DefaultEvent = {
  value: string
}

type SpecificEvent = {
  specificValue: string
}

function handleEvent<TEvent>(
  e: TEvent,
  extractor: (e: TEvent) => string
  // default extractor implementation should be (e) => e.value when TEvent is of type DefaultEvent
  ) {
    console.log(extractor(e));
}

handleEvent<DefaultEvent>({value: "test"}, (e) => e.value);
handleEvent<SpecificEvent>({specificValue: "test2"}, (e) => e.specificValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the types via function overloading, but you still need to provide the missing extractor is the function implementation. Here's [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBDArgG2AUQG4QHbCgF4oBvAKCii0VWQgC4oBnYAJwEtcBzMgXzLLxkuAMbB2Ae1xQAFolwATVBGx5gAHgAqq-FAgAPYHgVNYCFOh3AAfAAoKextpz4ANA4NtEYiawD8jLYMUM5qAJRE1sxsnDyUYYxYEuwKANyCwmKS0nKKylZaVnqGxqYSAEYAVhBidh5OVu6UnqzewL6BwaH4EYRRLBzcDglUyWkZouJSsvJKKi4a3QSepWZIaJgLUAA+UBXVtfbNDQtNxV4+-p0n4ZHRg3FQI0kppA6U7PC2AIQtbb4RciUYHnVqXIhQIK9KJBKCIUxwdaWBZhAB01FoEHeUH4IJEUiYEmUqNQEi4QUMYParChYXS-DIuTmVlsJAxdEYACIjCxObw6YzZvkFqymJARJ92CIAGo0DlQbkQFgAJj5rkhEGhelRYpqkplcs1qSAA)

Comment: Thanks - this works well. Is there a way to do this without explicitly having an overload for SpecificEvent? SpecificEvent could be an infinite amount of different events. `Conversion of type 'TEvent' to type 'SpecificEvent' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.ts(2352)` when leaving out `extends DefaultEvent | SpecificEvent` on the implementation.

Comment: @Dynamic I have updated the playground link in my answer, please check